# php artisan telescope:install not publishing the assets in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

i have a laravel 6 app that i want to install the telescope in that i did all the commands like `composer update` and `composer dump-autoload` and then i install the telescope every thing is going fine and when i run `php artisan telescope:install` i get the message below :

```
Publishing Telescope Service Provider...
Publishing Telescope Assets...
Publishing Telescope Configuration...
Telescope scaffolding installed successfully.
```

but it wont generate the config file and migration so when i run `php artisan migrate`
i get this message :

```
nothing to migrate
```

thus i cant access the telescope . please advice .

Comment: php artisan vendor:publish? maybe?

Comment: i cant get the telescope routes anyway it gives 404 not found and when i run php artisan route:list i cant see that in routes though i cleared cache and other things too

Comment: Have you install like : `composer require laravel/telescope
`

Comment: yes i did sir now i even have the provider added in config/app.php

Comment: php artisan telescope:publish U did?

Comment: yes i did that too

Answer (score 2):

For me, the installation was incomplete, so I comment the API provider and cleared the cache. And re-installed.

As given in the article: https://panjeh.medium.com/new-installation-of-laravel-telescope-fails-418afa2b8972

"was this new line in the config/app.php file:
App\Providers\TelescopeServiceProvider::class,
That causes the error and it seems the installation was not complete and only that line was added!
So I commented that line in the config/app.php file"

Answer (score 1):

You may use Composer to install Telescope into your Laravel project:

```
composer require laravel/telescope
```

After installing Telescope, publish its assets using the telescope:install Artisan command.

```
php artisan telescope:install
```

After installing Telescope, you should also run the migrate command:

```
php artisan migrate
```

Comment: @Farshad have you manged to fix this? It seems that more people have this issue, see https://github.com/laravel/telescope/issues/746

Comment: @eskimo for me it was my env file i have dissabled that there take a look at there to see if you enabled it in your env or not .

Comment: Not sure if I follow. What do you mean by ‘enabled it’?

Answer (score 1):

This works for me: `composer require laravel/telescope --dev`
 Full guide to install and set up Laravel Telescope
https://medium.com/@Zerquix18/full-guide-to-install-and-set-up-laravel-telescope-daf558f734f2